# ngrock exit when executed on macos 64x

Tags: macos

I am triying to execute the `rgrock` but the process is closed early. Giving a `[[Process Completed]]` message at the end without the ability to continue the normal functionality.

```
Last login: Thu Mar  4 13:47:54 on ttys002
/Users/macbook/slack-bot/ngrok ; exit;                        
macbook@Macbooks-MacBook-Pro ~ % /Users/macbook/software_projects/slack-bot/ngrok ; exit;
NAME:
   ngrok - tunnel local ports to public URLs and inspect traffic

... . . .

Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

I have managed to fire it up with the command `./ngrock http 80` but when I add the server port the mac bash doesnt recognizes ngrock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´ve found the problem. I don't know why its pretty different from windows.

Basically you have to do exactly the commands the `ngrock` gives (in its terminal) as soon as it open. So, I had to `cd` where `bgrock` is located and run the command from mac bash:

```
./ngrok http https://127.0.0.1:5000
```

Although it didn't run on its own terminal, I was able to run it from bash.

Comment: You can add the ngrok install location to your path or make a symlink, such as https://gist.github.com/wosephjeber/aa174fb851dfe87e644e

Answer (score 1):

In the command ./nrock http 80 You mis-spelled ngrok.